# Can ML Kit for Firebase be used for handwritten text?

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit

Concerning the new ML Kit for Firebase, all the examples I have seen from Google is recognizing "machine" text, but I was wondering if it is possible to use the new ML Kit for Firebase to extract handwritten characters as well?

I think not, but I cannot find the information in the documentation or anywhere (and no I have not tried to actually use ML Kit yet).

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Not sure why :). I upvoted for FWIW. Btw, may I know what  your use case is?

Comment: To recognize hand written notes with a mobile app

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I think the downvotes are because you haven't actually tried anything.

Comment: Well, maybe you are right. But I did try something: looking at the documentation and Google examples, which gave no clear conclusion. Yes, I did not implement anything. But I would have thought the point of asking a question is to save hours of implementation time of something that would not have worked anyway....but I guess some have another opinion on that:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right now, ML Kit does not work for a generic handwritten text sample but  only on handwritten text that is very well written and sparse. We are considering adding support for it in the upcoming releases.

Comment: That would surely be a nice future addition to ML Kit I think

Comment: I second that, and if there was a way to vote for that feature, I would.

Comment: I need that functionality too

Answer (score 2):

ML Kit just released a new API as "Digital Ink Recognition" which can recognize handwritten notes if it is written on a digital surface(stroke-based), check it out: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition